# How to make the site front page display the number of product SKUs ？

Tags: magento2

My product is a configurable product, I would like to show the number of product SKUs on the product page, switch each different color, show the number of SKUs for each different color。

Answer (score 0):

first you need to override the core module.
second create a function which can give you the products SKU which are associated to parent.
you can call this function(function will return an array of data use foreach loop) in phtml to display the sku.

create one more function pass 1 parameters, which is user input. Based on that display the data.